# How do I print a diamond shape that changes sizes based on the variable?

Tags: python

```
a = "*"
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n-1)-i),end = '')
    print(a*((i+1)*2-1))

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n+1)+i),end = '')
    print(a*((n-i)*2-1))


         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
           *******************
            *****************
             ***************
              *************
               ***********
                *********
                 *******
                  *****
                   ***
                    *
```

Comment: Is your question "How do I print the bottom half of the diamond so it isn't spaced over too far"?

Comment: oh yes. i was failing. everything i did, the bottom triangle either changed shapes, or it... changed places

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the logic and math inside the loops, just iterate backwards with:

```
for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
```

Which will count `i` from 9 to 0:

```
a = "*"
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(" " * ((n - 1) - i),end = '')
    print(a * ((i + 1) * 2 - 1))

for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
    print(" " * ((n - 1) - i),end = '')
    print(a * ((i + 1) * 2 - 1))
```

Prints:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

FWIW, you can also use python's text formatting to center a string inside a column width, which would simplify your code:

```
a = "*"
n = 15

for i in range(1, n):
    stars = a * (2 * i - 1)
    print('{:^{width}}'.format(stars, width=n*2))

for i in range(n - 2, 0, -1):
    stars = a * (2 * i - 1)
    print('{:^{width}}'.format(stars, width=n*2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.
You can just substract (n-1) to the second part so the two parts are aligned.

```
a = "*"
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n-1)-i),end = '')
    print(a*((i+1)*2-1))

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n+1)+i-n-1),end = '')
    print(a*((n-i)*2-1))
```

This prints:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

Answer (score 0):

You need exacly n spaces in front for the lower half:

```
a = "*"
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n-1)-i), end = '')
    print(a*((i+1)*2-1))

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*i, end = '')    
    print(a*((n-i)*2-1))
```

to get

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

Or you use the smart solution with formating your output centered:

```
for i in range(n): 
    print(f"{a*((i+1)*2-1):^{2*n}}")

for i in range(n): 
    print(f"{a*((n-i)*2-1):^{2*n}}")
```

which does exactly the same. See [string format mini languate (look for ^)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove (n+1)-i in the second loop and instead just use i. Because, when you look at it, as you start from the second half, you don't need any spaces for the first row, one blank space for row 2, 2 for row 3 and so on.

so the code will look like this:

```
a = "*"
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*((n-1)-i),end = '')
    print(a*((i+1)*2-1))

for i in range(n):
    print(" "*(i),end = '')
    print(a*((n-i)*2-1))
```

hope it's helpful!